# get_%field%_display without instance

Tags: django

I have a model like this

```
class Item(models.Model):
    STATUS_VALID = 1
    STATUS_INVALID = 2
    STATUS_UNKNOWN = 3

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_VALID, _("Valid")),
        (STATUS_INVALID, _("Invalid")),
        (STATUS_UNKNOWN, _("Unknown")),
    )

    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_UNKNOWN)
```

I already know that I can use `instance.get_status_display()` to get string value for an instance, but how can get this value without an instance, I mean something like this

```
Item.get_status_display(Item.STATUS_VALID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i can see, the simple way is: convert the `STATUS_CHOICES` to dict and get the value, for example:

```
dict(Item.STATUS_CHOICES).get(Item.STATUS_VALID)
```